# .htaccess redirect to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need to redirect on this format:

https://old.com/pages/1248/some-title

https://new.com/pages/1248/some-title

I have tray this code:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(\d+)/[^/]+$ https://new.com/pages/$1/+[^/] [R=301,L]
```

but the rezult faill on the "some-title" and look like this:
https://new.com/pages/1248/%2B%5B%5E/%5D

Answer (score 0):

Solvet

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(\d+)/(.*) https://new.com/pages/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

adding `(.*)` will work